# Open application from scanned qr code in default camera

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-manifest, qr-code, android-13

I am using breoadcast receiver to open my app when scanning a qr code from the device default camera. I tested this with Android 11 and Android 12 and it works fine. When I tried this out with Android 13 the qr string is shown when I click on it, it's opened on the browser.
Here is my implementation of the Qr code scan method:

In AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.cibingenierie.nomadmobile.screens.MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>


    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="nm" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

On MainActivity.kt

here is my onCrete function

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val intent = intent
    val data = intent.data.toString()

    val dataArgs = data.replace("nm://", "")

    onBroadcastReceived()
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)

    setContent {
        AppTheme {
            NomadApplication(userViewModel, registerViewModel, ticketViewModel,intent)
        }
    }
}
```

and onBroadcastReceived function

```
private fun onBroadcastReceived() {
    val receiver = (object : ExternalReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val launchIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN")
            launchIntent.putExtra("camera", "")
            context.startActivity(launchIntent)
        }
    })
}
```

Can you please help me fix this?

I dont get an error it's actually the qr code string always detected as a web url

Comment: You can try to look into deep linking: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking
This is a special link which will be opened by your app if it is installed.

Comment: @Bennik2000 Yes, I am initializing my app link in manifest and calling it in onCreate. It actually has this format nm:// but it doesn't launch the app when scanned with default camera.

Comment: Do you have a domain which is associated with the nm:// scheme? Maybe you have to define a concrete domain and verify associated links: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks